# How to get length of items inside ng-repeat or with ng-init with filters

Tags: angularjs

I need a length of filtered `bookshelf` here are what i have.

Models:
1. Book: id, category_id 
2. Bookshelf: id, book_id, read_book

```
<div ng-repeat = 'book in filteredBooks = (books | filter: {category_id: 5})'>
  <div ng-init = 'filteredBookshelf = (bookshelf | filter: {read_book:true}).length'> 
    {{filteredBookshelf}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15503/)

Maybe i can filtered it in controller some how. For example:

```
$scope.bookshelfLength = $filter('filter')(bookshelf, {book.category_id: 5, read_book: true}).length
```

**Description of logic**

I = current_user 
50 books with different categories are in DB. 30 of them I have on my bookshelf and 10 of 30 has category_id:5, and 3 of this 10 are read`read_book:true`. So in my case `filteredBookshelf` should be 3

Comment: As answered below, the `filteredBooks` is the filtered array alias... but, what is the need for `ng-init` below - seems wonky

Comment: @NewDev yes looks not ok. My goal is get `filteredBookshelf `  only for specific book category.

Comment: What is `bookshelf` and what is the relationship of `bookshelf` to `books`

Comment: Sure appears that you don't need new instance of `filteredBookshelf` for every repeated item since it doesn't seem to have any dependency on `book` instance

Comment: @charlietfl I agree but how i can filter books by `category_id` first and then filter by `book_read`

Comment: Can you create simple plunker demo? Not 100% sure what you are trying to do. Seeing some sample data might help. I think you need a `bookshelf` filter in `ng-repeat`

Comment: @charlietfl [here is](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15503/)

Comment: Still not clear why you aren't looping over `bookshelf` or what expectations are by doing what you are doing

Comment: maybe you want something like this using a custom "isRead" filter http://plnkr.co/edit/olxsRWGpeSPgSDaVEqZW?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl Yes. Custom filter works for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like

`len = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

`<div ng-repeat="l in len | filter:3 as p"> {{ l }}{{ p.length }}</div>  // 3 1`

In your case

`<div ng-repeat = 'book in filteredBooks = (books | filter: {category_id: 5}) as filtered'>`

`{{ filtered.length }}`

Example in plkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ye6ARaJdBxJVyCXc4cqR?p=info